# How to get only relations from eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I got the following code:

`$popularProducts = PopularProduct::with('product')->get();`

This is how I get all of products from `popular_products` (contains only `product_id`) table with relations for `products` table. But I have this result:

```
Collection {#409 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => PopularProduct {#411 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:4 [▶]
      #original: array:4 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "product" => Product {#462 ▶}
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to take only `relations->product` field. How can I take it?

Comment: Try `foreach($popularProducts->product as product)`

Answer (score 19):

You can do it like this

```
$products = PopularProduct::with('product')->get()->pluck('product');
```

if you like  the result to be  keyed you can do it like this

```
$products = PopularProduct::with('product')->get()->pluck('product','id');
```

`// you can key it with **id** of the table (popularProduct) or by` `**id_product** of relationship (product)`

if you like only to retrieve specific fields from relation you can try something like this

```
 $products = PopularProduct::with('product:id,product_name')->get()->pluck('product','id');
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `whereHas` method (if there is a relationship between these tables)

```
$popular_products = Product::whereHas('products', function ($query) {
      $query->where('popular_products',$ids);
 })->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the collection:

```
@foreach ($popularProducts as $popularProduct)
    {{ $popularproduct->product->id }}
@endforeach
```

If you just want to get all products from the collection, use the `pluck()` method:

```
$products = $popularProducts->pluck('product');
```

**Update**

In the comments, you've said you want to get `links` directly from DB:

```
Product::has('popularProduct')->pluck('links');
```

This will work if you've defined the `popularProduct` relationship in the `Product` model.

Comment: This is good, but how can I use any filters (I need to use linkFilter) from `Product` model in this case? I need something like: `PopularProduct::with('product')->get()->pluck('product')->link()`, but we need to use filters only from query builder, not from collection

Comment: This is probably my bad. I have an scope in Product model:`public function scopeLink($query) {
        //some $query
        return $query;
    }`, and I need to use it like `Product::get()->link()`, not with `pluck` from collection.

Comment: @Alexxosipov scope is just a way to reuse code. You can't load scope into the collection with `get()` or something.

Comment: Yes. I find a solution with: `PopularProduct::with('product')->link()->get()`, it works fine.